# How to append function to an array?

Tags: arrays, function, julia

For example, I can create an array that contains a function.

```
julia> a(x) = x + 1
>> a (generic function with 1 method)

julia> [a]
>> 1-element Array{#a,1}:
    a
```

But I can't seem to add the function to an empty array:

```
julia> append!([],a)

>> ERROR: MethodError: no method matching length(::#a)
  Closest candidates are:
    length(::SimpleVector) at essentials.jl:168
    length(::Base.MethodList) at reflection.jl:256
    length(::MethodTable) at reflection.jl:322
    ...
   in _append!(::Array{Any,1}, ::Base.HasLength, ::Function) at .\collections.jl:25
   in append!(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function) at .\collections.jl:21
```

What I ulimately want to do is store the pre-defined functions so that I can ultimately map them over a value. E.g.:

```
x = 0.0

for each fn in vec
    x = x + fn(x)    
end
```

Comment: Second parameter of [`append!`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/stdlib/collections/?highlight=append#Base.append!) is a collection. You may use `push!([], a)` for individual items, or `append!([], [a])` for a collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`append!` is for appending one collection on to another.
You are looking for `push!`, to add an element to a collection.

Your code should be `push!([], a)`

See the docs:

```
julia>?append!

search: append!

append!(collection, collection2) -> collection.

Add the elements of collection2 to the end of collection.

julia> append!([1],[2,3])
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> append!([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6

Use push! to add individual items to collection which are not already themselves in another collection. The result is of the preceding example is equivalent to push!([1, 2, 3], 4, 5, 6).
```

vs:

```
julia>?push!

search: push! pushdisplay

push!(collection, items...) -> collection

Insert one or more items at the end of collection.

julia> push!([1, 2, 3], 4, 5, 6)
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6

Use append! to add all the elements of another collection to collection. The result of the preceding example is equivalent to append!([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]).
```